# TSI (Trend strength Index) - What is the formula being used here?

Tags: linear-transformations

On Binance trading platform - There is a built-in indicator which at first look seems as a traditional TSI indicator. They called it Trend strength indicator which from my research are usually giving the index in the range of -40 to 40 and some variation of that - This one is in the range of 1 to -1 and doesnot map to the traditional indicators. I thought maybe its  a ROC indicator (based on the range) but as you can see it is not.
I'm trying to find and understand how the indicator is calculated but can find nothing binance and google.

Maybe some of you know which formula is used to calculate this indicator?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't be fully sure but it looks like a [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient).  Why?  Well, the number is almost 1 when there is a clear upward trend, and the number is almost -1 when there is a clear downward trend, which matches the behavior of the standard correlation coefficient.  It probably uses the most recent few minutes of data to calculate it (as the chart is only for four hours of data), but I'm not certain how much.